# How to calculate mean value with respect to the month in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the average with respect to the months of data in DRF. I have two problems here my values in the string so I need to convert first into double and then calculate it. I am not able to think any solution that's why posting the question without my solution what I have tried.

My modal class is:

```
class FeedDataValues(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.SensorDevice',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    hardware_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    received_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

My serializer class is:

```
class MQTTFeedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FeedDataValues
        fields = ('id','sensor','hardware_id','field1','field2','received_at',)
```

And views is:

```
class MQTTFeedDataListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = serializers.MQTTFeedDataSerializer
    queryset = models.FeedDataValues.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = filters.MQTTFeedValuesFilter
```

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: which value are you trying to take average of? have you implemented in the code anywhere already?

Comment: field1 and field2 I am trying to get the average.

Comment: It will be possible to do this with Django query but you need to specify your problem more clearly. If you don't have any query, may be just sending an example of what you want to achieve will help.